# How can I make generic<> this method --> OpenForm() I don't want to create method for each form

Tags: c#

```
UIDirector directorUI = new UIDirector();
UIActor actorUI = new UIActor();
private void directorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenForm(directorUI);
}
private void actorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenForm(actorUI);
}

void OpenForm(Form frm)
{
    if (frm.IsDisposed)
    {
        frm = new UIDirector();
    }
    frm.Show();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
}
```

Comment: Look into dependency injection and having your UIActor and UIDirector implementing a UI Interface.

Comment: You can create a generic class that would handle generic forms?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what you were asking, and decided to create a new answer.

Make an extension method for it.

```
public static class UIExtensions
{
  public static void Present(this Form form, Form parent)
  {
    form.MdiParent = parent;
    form.Show();
  }
}
```

Then you can just `actorUI.Present(this);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `new` generic constrain to create specific object with parameterless constructor.

```
UIDirector directorUI = new UIDirector();
UIActor actorUI = new UIActor();
private void directorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenForm(directorUI);
}
private void actorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenForm(actorUI);
}

void OpenForm<T>(T frm) where T: Form, new()
{
    if (frm.IsDisposed)
    {
        frm = new T();
    }
    frm.Show();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
}
```